# Accessing values in Postgres array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, where-clause, sql-null

I want to run a query like this where `params` is a `text` array:

```
select * from table_name where params[10]<>'Retail'
```

"Give me rows whose params array does not contain the value Retail at index 10"

There are several rows that should statisfy that condition, i.e. they have something other than 'Retail' at that array index. But still I get 0 rows.

However, if I do

```
select * from table_name where params[10]='Retail'
```

Then I get rows as expected i.e. non 'Retail' rows are filtered out.

Also, `select params[10] from table_name` gives a number of rows with values like

```
{Retail}
{HNI}
```

Where as I am expecting:

```
Retail
HNI
```

This tells me, I am getting an array instead of a the value at that index. How do I extract the raw text value from an array so that I can use it in where clause etc.?

Postgres version: 13.1

Client: DBeaver 7.0.0

Comment: It would be good to see `\d table_name` and `SELECT params FROM table_name;` (excerpts) when run with `psql`.

Comment: `params[10]` works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=31a24b6a2c0629a172fa048e0e7f1b27 Could you provide a fiddle to show the problem?

Comment: It seems the array data was not consistent, some rows contained more array elements than others. So the value I was looking for was at a slightly sifted index on some rows.This was not evident when just looking at the whole stringified array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you want `is distinct from` instead if `<>`, so `null` values are properly handled, as well as arrays that have less than 10 elements:

```
select * from table_name where params[10] is distinct from 'Retail'
```